# basic node.js tutorial error Object function router(req, res, next) has no method init

Tags: express, webstorm

I am new to Express and Webstorm and am working on a simple tutorial at http://www.mattpalmerlee.com/2012/11/09/getting-started-with-node-js-express-and-jade-using-the-webstorm-ide/

I believe that I have followed all instructions correctly and even fixed the typos on the site (user vs. users etc.)

At the end, I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/node app.js

/home/admin/WebstormProjects/MyNode/app.js:61 users.init();
      ^
    TypeError: Object function router(req, res, next) {
        router.handle(req, res, next);
      } has no method 'init'
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/admin/WebstormProjects/MyNode/app.js:61:7)
        at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
        at startup (node.js:119:16)
        at node.js:902:3

Process finished with exit code 8
```

I think that this is due to Express version incompatibility.  I did read the changes doc for Express 4, but I still cannot debug this error.

Comment: Have a look at videos here: http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/05/guide-to-node-js-development-with-webstorm/
And try exports.init()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `exports.init()` to `router.init()`:

```
router.init = function() {
    users.push(new User('Matt', 'Palmerlee', '818-123-4567'));
    users.push(new User('Joe', 'Plumber', '310-012-9876'));
    users.push(new User('Tom', 'Smith', '415-567-2345'));
}


/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {

    res.render('users', {'users':users, 'title':'Users'});
});
```

Also, make sure to run `node bin\www` instead of `node app.js`

Comment: Thanks, it took care of it, and it now works.  I am still confused by the routing terminology in users.js.  I always thought that the router.get('/' will take you to the default route (index.js in this case).  But I can also see why it works now.  Any clarification will be nice!